# Question on hold in improved form - can it be re-openned?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question and in comments, a user here helped me to heavily improve the question, but it was afterwards put on hold.

The question's close reasons appears to have nothing to do with [it's current state](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23769/why-did-we-use-the-threshold-between-the-definitions-of-human-embryo-and-human-f#23772), as suggested in comments.

Comment: I think it will be re-openened. You already got four votes in favor of it, so this is only a matter of time. As not always a lot of people are around, it can take a few hours...

Answer (score 1):

Your post has been reopened.

Because you have close/reopen vote privileges on your own questions (see the full [list of privileges](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) you currently have/can acquire in the future), If this situation comes up again, there is no need to write a meta post. Simply cast a reopen vote on the question, and it will be added to the [reopen queue](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/reopen), where the community can decide it's future. Posting in meta is not necessary *unless* it is voted to remain closed, and you would like advice on how to bring it within scope.

Wow, that was longer than it could have been. Anyway, have fun and stay on-topic! :)